# How to dynamic change component template at runtime?. Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a menu bar and action panel. A action panel is just simple div in which inside I want to display different components.

For example:
User click button A -> display Component A in action panel;
User click button B -> display Component B in action panel;

What is the best way to do this?

I thought to use ngswtich in my template, for example (pseudocode!).

```
<div id="action-panel">
    <div [ngSwitch]="componentType">         
        <div *ngSwitchCase="userComponent">
            <user-component></user-component>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use routing to this, you can navigate through different views.
see more at https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the routing and use sub routing for it.
Place a new `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside or instead of your action-panel and do sub state component.

This is a really good read and might enlighten you: 
http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/

Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Submodule routing and nested <router-outlet>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857876/angular-2-submodule-routing-and-nested-router-outlet)